# Images don't appear when I HTML my markdown

Tags: markdown

Probably simple but I just can't figure it out.  I made a markdown document in Sublime 3 and published it with Markdown Preview.  Looks fine on my machine.  But when I open it another machine, none of the images appear.  Bear in mind I am new to all this.  But what am I supposed to do? Share the entire folder (.md file and images)?

Comment: For the markdown file? In a folder on my desktop. The images are in the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the .md file references local images (Not on the web) then moving the .md fie to a different location, away from the images will break the link.  You need to share all of the content or host the images somewhere reference-able from both locations

Comment: I see. But why then can I use knitr in Rstudio to make an html file that where images are local but not lost when I share the html file?

Comment: The generated HTML will still contain local relative links to the images.  If the images are uploaded and hosted (and the references changed to those hosted links) then even after being turned into HTML the images will continue to work

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.  So does knitr essentially host the images for you when you compile through Rstudio? Perhaps I am still missing something.  Sorry to be so elementary.